# Fluids with critical point at ordinary temperature and pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, physical-chemistry, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

Are there any fluids with critical point near [STP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_conditions_for_temperature_and_pressure) or that are [supercritical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_fluid) at STP?

If not would it be feasible to design a molecule for a substance with critical point near STP using theoretical/computational methods?

---

### Update

@Diracology and @Floris's great answers helped me find large carbon chain molecules, particularly those with large numbers of fluoride atom, that $P_c < 10\, atm$ and $T_c < 1000K$. That is within the reach of a good bicycle pump and a burner. In particular:

- [$C_{12}F_{26}$](https://www.chemeo.com/cid/10-804-7/n-Perfluorododecane) | $P_c = 912\, kPa\ |\ T_c = 417\, K$
- [$C_{15}H_4F_{28}O$](https://www.chemeo.com/cid/75-143-0/1H,1H,15H-Octacosafluoro-1-pentadecanol.pdf) | $P_c = 784\, kPa\ |\ T_c = 701\, K$
- [$C_{20}F_{42}$](https://www.chemeo.com/cid/12-080-9/Perfluoroeicosane) | $P_c = 463\, kPa\ |\ T_c = 700\, K$

Given @Diracology and @Floris's answer, that suggests that **something like $C_{100}F_{202}$ could be critical at around ordinary pressure and an easily achievable temperature**, ie it might be possible to get a critical fluid by heating some goop in an open saucepan.

Unfortunately this is ignoring the availability, cost and safe handling of such a substance, but otherwise it could make one hell of a Youtube video :).

It is going to be a tough call awarding the bounty which has already been well earned by both @Diracology and @Floris.

Comment: If it makes your decision easier, award the bounty to @Diracology's answer. Without that answer, I would not have explored the design space in the way I did - in particular I would not have remembered that there are expressions (idealized but useful) that capture the relationships between Van der Waals forces and $P_c, T_c$

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41345/room-conditions-supercritical-fluids

Comment: Nice question and answers. You could accept one answer and give the bounty to the other....  Do the molecules you mentioned exist?

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier I think they exist, I found them in the chemical databases that they are linked to in the question.

Comment: @DanielMahler: If I click on your chemical formulas I only get a pop-up menu for mathjax information, not a link to a database entry.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier What browser are you using? They work for me in chrome, even on my phone.

Comment: Indeed, it works with Chromium but not with Firefox.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier I just checked and firefox does work for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whether an answer exists depends on your definition of "near" compared to STP.

There are a few fluids that have their critical point at a *temperature* close to STP, but higher pressure. For example, (see http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/critical-point-d_997.html)

```
  material   Tc(K)    Pc(atm)
acetylene    309.5     61.6
ethylene     283.1     50.5
ethane       305.5     48.2
```

All these are non-polar molecules with a very modest atomic mass. As soon as you add oxygen, the critical temperature increases by a lot, while the pressure comes down only slightly:

```
acetone       508       48
acetaldehyde  466       55
```

The problem is that for a critical point to exist near atmospheric pressure, your liquid needs to have a density close to that of the vapor at atmospheric pressure. And that would require an extremely low-density liquid. Or a high-density gas.

**UPDATE**

It is possible (as shown by @Diracology) to estimate the Van der Waals coefficients of the substance that would have the desired properties.
Following those calculations (for which a derivation can be found [here](http://cbc.arizona.edu/~salzmanr/480a/480ants/vdwcrit/vdwcrit.html), I computed the Van der Waals coefficients $a$ and $b$ for a few small molecules. Plotting the volume (computed from critical parameters) against number of atoms in these molecules gives a "reasonable straight line". When I extrapolate that line (which is NOT a reasonable thing to do), I find that the X molecule would contain about 300 atoms:

[image]

(note - while I show pressure in atm in the table, I convert to Pa for the calculation).

As you can see - the hard thing is to get a molecule with such high intermolecular attraction (a=25; the most polar molecule in the list, acetone, has a=1.6 so you are about 15x off your target); but if you want to play with your computer model to create such a molecule, I think it could be fun.

Just to help with the optimization, here is a graph showing the behavior of $a$ and $b$ and their effect of $T_c$ and $P_c$ (source code to generate this shown below).

[image]

And the source code:

```
#critical point calcs
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import pi

# constants
R=8.31
Na=6.02E23
#number of lines for a,b
N1=5
N2=5

def pc(a,b):
    return a/(27.0*b*b)

def tc(a,b):
    return 8*a/(27*b*R)

# range of values for a,b:
a = np.logspace(-0.5,1.5,N1)
b = np.logspace(-4,-2,N2)

T = np.zeros((N1,N2))
P = np.zeros((N1,N2))

for ii in range(N2):
    for jj in range(N1):
        T[jj,ii]=tc(a[jj],b[ii])
        P[jj,ii]=pc(a[jj],b[ii])

Tc = 293
Pc = 1e5
plt.figure()
plt.loglog(T,P,'b')
plt.loglog(T.T,P.T,'r')
plt.loglog([Tc,Tc],[1e2,Pc],'g')
plt.loglog([1,Tc],[Pc,Pc],'g')
plt.xlabel('Tc')
plt.ylabel('Pc')
plt.title('critical point for different a and b')
plt.xlim((1e1,1e4))
plt.ylim((1e3,1e8))


bc = R*Tc/(8*Pc)
ac = 27*bc*bc*Pc
vc = bc/(4*Na)
rc = np.power(3*vc/(4*pi),1./3.)
t = '  a=%.1f, b=%.4f; r=%.2e'%(ac,bc,rc)
plt.annotate(t, xy=(Tc,Pc), verticalalignment='top')
plt.annotate('increasing b', xy=(0.4, 0.1), xycoords='axes fraction',
                xytext=(0.2, 0.6), textcoords='axes fraction',
                arrowprops=dict(facecolor='blue', edgecolor='none', shrink=0.05),
                horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='top',
                )
plt.annotate('increasing a', xy=(0.8, 0.6), xycoords='axes fraction',
                xytext=(0.3, 0.7), textcoords='axes fraction',
                arrowprops=dict(facecolor='red', edgecolor='none', shrink=0.05),
                horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='top',
                )
plt.show()
```

Comment: The comex deep dives subjected people to these pressures, so it may be possible to swim in supercritical fluids.

Comment: I am after something that allows very low tech demonstration of criticality. I would probably take something with ordinary pressure and vary the temperature. Say something that goes critical by heating in a saucepan or chucking some (dry) ice in.

Comment: I recall being shown a demo with a liquid in a strong glass container (yes I suppose it was probably over 60 atm inside). Quite feasible, but maybe not as low tech as you are looking for.

Comment: @DanielMahler , does your demo require a pure component, or would a mixture also suffice?  If you can tolerate a mixture, you should have a LOT more degrees of freedom regarding the physical properties that can be achieved.

Comment: @DavidWhite My "demo" is purely hypothetical at the moment. Mixtures would be just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the plots that is helpful. After a little search I was able to find a substance with [$P_c = 8 atm$](https://www.chemeo.com/cid/75-143-0/1H,1H,15H-Octacosafluoro-1-pentadecanol.pdf)

Comment: It has a critical temperature of 700 K...

Comment: Yes but 700 K should be achievable with minimal tech requirements. Many fuels burn at several times that. This shows that you and @Diracology pointed me in the right direction in a direction. Just by looking around for substances with a high $a$ and $b$ known substances that are a lot closer then what I was previously aware of. Makes me thing that actually designing such a molecule could be feasible.

Answer (score 6):

The critical pressure is given by
$$P_c=\frac{a}{27b^2},$$
while the critical temperature is
$$T_c=\frac{8a}{27bR}=\frac{8bP_c}{R}.$$
The parameter $b$ is related to to the [effective volume occupied by the molecules](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37470/why-do-we-take-4-times-the-volume-of-a-molecule-for-calculating-the-van-der-waal?rq=1),
$$b=4N_0V_0,$$
where $V_0$ is the volume of the molecule and $N_0$ is the Avogadro number.

So at least theoretically you can chose $P_c=1\, \mathrm{atm}\approx 10^5\, \mathrm{Pa}$ and $T_c=273\, \mathrm{K}$ and then solve it for $b$,
$$b=\frac{RT_c}{8P_c}\approx 2.7\cdot 10^{-3},$$
which means a molecule radius of $6.4\cdot 10^{-10}\, \mathrm{m}$, which is reasonable.  If you want just to make a model, you can fix $T_c=273\, \mathrm{K}$ and $a\sim 10^0$ (which is the highest value I have seen) and then solve for $P_c$ and $b$. Then you will find how far from $1\, \mathrm{atm}$ and a tipical radius $10^{-10}$ the solution is.

Comment: Very nice! What is $a$ and how did you eliminate that from the initial equations?

Comment: The parameter $a$ characterizes the strength of the attractive intermolecular interaction  and it has a quite large range of values for different molecules. However since it appears equally in the expression for $P_c$ and $T_c$ we can eliminate it with those expressions.

Comment: Nice analysis - but now that you have $b$, you need to calculate $a$ as well - the other Van der Waals coefficient. Using your numbers, I get $a=20$ - that seems an order of magnitude too large for any known materials. Thoughts?

Comment: @Floris Thanks for pointing this out. It is correct, this is way above a realistic value for $a$ which in the table I have at hands is of order $10^{-3}-10^{-1}$. I think that is where your answer comes in.  We can play with the relations for $P_c$ and $T_c$ but we can't get exactly the STP conditions. How near we get is, as you said, a matter of definition.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ independent or is there some correlation between them?

Comment: @DanielMahler $a$ relates to the attractive forces between the molecules; $b$ is a proxy for their volume. They are independent; but it is hard to imagine a large molecule with a sufficiently large $a$ (I suppose a crazy surface of alternating electrophilic and electrophobic atoms would be needed).

Comment: @Floris and Diactology Designing a molecule with maximal $a$ for a fixed $b$ is the kind of problem that could be attacked by computational methods. About how many atoms are there in a $6.4 \times 10^{-10}m$ molecule?

Comment: Incidentally [this link](http://cbc.arizona.edu/~salzmanr/480a/480ants/vdwcrit/vdwcrit.html) gives a very accessible derivation of the expressions used here.

Comment: @DanielMahler You can try fixing $T_c=273$ and $a\sim 10^{0}$ (which is the highest value I have seen) and then solve for $P_c$ and $b$.

Comment: As for your question about size - if we assume the derivation is accurate, we can compute the size of different molecules by looking at their critical pressure / temperature; I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Candidate substances can also be found using [group contribution methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_contribution_method)
such as the [Klincewicz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klincewicz_method) and [Joback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joback_method) methods, which predict substance properties by taking weighted counts of atomic groups within the molecule.
Bothe of the above named methods predict $T_c$ and $P_c$. These methods are only heuristic though and it is not clear what their domain of validity is.
In particular they can not distinguish beween isomers of a molecule which have significant effects on $T_c$ and $P_c$.

It is still interesting to see what insights these methods can provide. Inspecting the formula and tables of these methods shows that the dominant trend is that $P_c$ decreases with increasing number of atoms and molecular  weight while $T_c$ with the specifics of the molecule providing corrections to the rate of this effect. This is consistent with the relationship between $T_c$, $P_c$ and Van der Waals $b$ in @Floris and @Diracology's answers as well as my finding of low $P_c$ substances among large flourocarbons.

The need for large molecules implies a carbon backbone. The remaining constituents can the be chosen to try and minimize the associated rise in $T_c$. According to the Joback method. Fluorine does appear to be one of the best constituents for this purpose.